# Minipage pictures not aligning

Tags: minipage, includegraphics

I am trying to make a series a pictures (around 5-6 or so) with the layout seen below, but when i write it in LaTeX using minipages it does not align the pictures properly, even though the minipages os the same width, aswell as the images.

This is the LaTeX output:

[image: LaTeX Output]

This is the code:

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \subsubsection{Rundsav}
    Rundsaven bruges til at save træ med. Man kan bruge, som set på figur !!!!!!!!, en stopklods, til at sikre sig at alle stykker træ man saver er lige store, og har samme mål. 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{teknik/rundsav}
\end{minipage}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \subsubsection{Sømpistol}
    Sømpistolen bruges til at skyde søm ind siderne på træet, der hvor to sider mødes. Sømpistolen bruger trykluft til at skyde med. 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{teknik/sømpistol}
\end{minipage}
```

How would i go about fixing this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try adding `\raggedleft` at the beginning of the minipages containing the images?

Comment: Thanks! It still displays shifted in a weird way

Comment: impossible to say with the information given. Try changing both images to `example-image` (a widely available test) then post a complete small document that shows the problem so we can debug.

Comment: If you don't need captions, just the images, try with the`\InsertBoxR{…}` command, from the plainTeX macro package `insbox`.

Comment: I tried to add more minipages as i did previously and it seems to work now, but the last image is always shifted that way.